# How to calculate the maximum occurance in a rolling window?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a data frame as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Type       | Incident ID     | Date of incident|
--------------------------------------------------
| A          | 1               | 2022-02-12      |
| A          | 2               | 2022-02-14      |
| A          | 3               | 2022-02-14      |
| A          | 4               | 2022-02-14      |
| A          | 5               | 2022-02-16      |
| A          | 6               | 2022-02-17      |
| A          | 7               | 2022-02-19      |
| A          | 8               | 2022-02-19      |
| A          | 7               | 2022-02-19      |
| A          | 8               | 2022-02-19      |

 ...          ...               ...             

| B          | 1               | 2022-02-12      |
| B          | 2               | 2022-02-12      |
| B          | 3               | 2022-02-13      |

 ...          ...               ...             

--------------------------------------------------
```

This is a list of different types of incidents. Every incident has a type, an id and a date, at which it occurred. This is just an example to help understand my goal.

What I want is - for a given range, e.g. 5 days - the maximum value that a rolling sum over these incidents would become:

So I would start with all elements that fall into the first 5 days and accumulate the occurences: 6.

```
2022-02-12 - 2022-02-17:    6
```

By starting to roll the window by one day, all elements of the first day get eliminated from the sum, in this case -1 and no element for the next day in line gets added. The next value would be 5.

```
2022-02-13 - 2022-02-18:    5
```

6 > 5. So 6 is still the maximum occurence of incidents in a 5 day window.

Continue for the complete time range.

This is not that hard to achieve but how would I do this in a very efficient manner for millions of elements? In short: I want to create a moving window of a fixed date range (e.g. 5 days), count all occurances for this window and give out the maximum value that was reached for any window.

Comment: Do you want the result for each type?

Comment: Yes, i would like to have the result for each of the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` to compute the dense matrix (Date, Type) then `resample` to fill missing dates. Finally apply a rolling sum along index axis:

```
df['Date of incident'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of incident'])

out = (df.pivot_table(index='Date of incident', columns='Type',
                      values='Incident ID', aggfunc='count')
         .resample('D').sum().rolling('5D', closed='both').sum().astype(int))
```

**EDIT**: I think `pd.crosstab` may be faster than `pd.pivot_table`:

```
out = (pd.crosstab(df['Date of incident'], df['Type'])
         .resample('D').sum().rolling('5D', closed='both').sum().astype(int))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
Type              A  B
Date of incident          
2022-02-12        1  2
2022-02-13        1  3
2022-02-14        4  3
2022-02-15        4  3
2022-02-16        5  3
2022-02-17        6  3  # A: 6 between 2022-02-12 and 2022-02-17 included
2022-02-18        5  1  # A: 5 between 2022-02-13 and 2022-02-18 included
2022-02-19        9  0
```

**Note**: compute all combinations can be a heavy process.

With this shape, you can plot your data easily:

```
out.plot(figsize=(6, 4), title='Rolling count (5 days)',
         ylabel='Number of incident', xlabel='Date')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That works like a charm. The only thing I am worried about is adding rows for dates without incidents. Couldn't this get very time consuming?

Comment: It's a good question and I have no answer because it depends on many parameters. However, the conversion between sparse to dense array can be memory consuming.

Comment: FYI: You can just omit the resampling of dates. The rolling function has a time window capability. Have a look here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13513

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research and it seems that `pd.rolling(window=5)` is quite costly when it comes to big datasets and especially on multiple columns.

However, I believe that `pd.Grouper()` is what you need.

here is the snippet code I did

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    'type': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
    'time': [
            '2022-02-12', '2022-02-13',
            '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14',
            '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14',
            '2022-02-17', '2022-02-17',
            '2022-02-18', '2022-02-19',
            '2022-02-21', '2022-02-21',
            '2022-02-22', '2022-02-22']
            }
test = pd.DataFrame(data).astype({'time': 'datetime64[ns]'})

#rollingg = test.rolling(window=5)
#(
#   test.assign(result= rollingg.ID.count())
#)

# Here, we group every 5 days together and we count, if you need the type 
#  into account, just add it to the groupby
(
   test
   .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='5D', closed='left')])
   .agg(counted=pd.NamedAgg(column='ID', aggfunc='count'))
)
```

[image: Here is the output of the previous code]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you so much. Though instead of a fixed time frame, as in every 5 days, I would need a moving window. So that the set of elements changes by 1 day every step. So in this case the window would start at 2022-02-12 then 2022-02-13 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach: Firstly, I have grouped the data on the basis of incident type and date and then add the incidents.

```
# Sample data
data={"Type":list("A"*10)+list("B"*10),
"Incident_ID":np.arange(20),
"Date":['2022-02-12', '2022-02-13', '2022-02-14','2022-02-14','2022-02-14','2022-02-15','2022-02-15',
                '2022-02-16', '2022-02-17', '2022-02-18', '2022-02-19','2022-02-19','2022-02-19',
                '2022-02-20', '2022-02-21', '2022-02-22', '2022-02-23',
                '2022-02-24', '2022-02-25', '2022-02-26']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())

   Type Incident_ID       Date
0   A      0        2022-02-12
1   A      1        2022-02-13
2   A      2        2022-02-14
3   A      3        2022-02-14
4   A      4        2022-02-14

# Step 1
df1=df.groupby(["Type","Date"],as_index=False).size().rename(columns={"size":"No_of_incidents"})
print(df1.head())

  Type        Date  No_of_incidents
0   A   2022-02-12       1
1   A   2022-02-13       1
2   A   2022-02-14       3
3   A   2022-02-15       2
```

Now I have created two columns rolling_ID1(sum of first 5) and rolling_ID2(sum of next 5). The rolling_ID2 is shifted 1 step up in order to match rolling_ID1.

```
# Only for Type-A:
df2=df1[df1['Type']=="A"].assign(rolling_ID1=df1['No_of_incidents'].rolling(5).sum(),
          rolling_ID2=df1.iloc[1:,:]['No_of_incidents'].rolling(5).sum().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Finally, I'm adding max_incidents column that shows max value between rolling_ID1 & ID2.

```
df2['max_incidents']=df2[['rolling_ID1','rolling_ID2']].max(axis=1)
print(df2.head())

  Type        Date  No_of_incidents rolling_ID1 rolling_ID2 max_incidents
0   A   2022-02-12         1                NaN        NaN        NaN
1   A   2022-02-13         1                NaN        NaN        NaN
2   A   2022-02-14         3                NaN        NaN        NaN
3   A   2022-02-15         2                NaN        NaN        NaN
4   A   2022-02-16         1                8.0        8.0        8.0
5   A   2022-02-17         1                8.0        8.0        8.0
6   A   2022-02-18         1                8.0        8.0        8.0
```

Comment: I will try out this approach as well. Thanks!